# How to pull the Git Repositories to new directory?

Tags: git, github

I have lost my local backup of repositories..how can I pull all data of that Repositories to a new dir...?I am using the software SmartGit to do actions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhm, maybe I did not understand the question correctly, but isn't a `git clone` of each repository the solution?

Edit after your comments: I've found this solution, see if it works fo you [GIT clone repo across local file system in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system)

To sum up you could try doing a `git clone file:////127.0.0.1/code`

Comment: i lost every thing in my local , i have a repos  name AA , i just want to copy/clone all the data of AA so that i can work like previously..when i do clone , it shoes that 'i hv colned an empty repos..'

Comment: So... if AA is the repository you want your work from, you could do `git clone AA`. Or... if you have the files but not the git repository  you could do `git init .` once inside the directory. Remember to copy your old `.git/config` into your new `.git/config`

Comment: yes... i think i miss something in cmd line... 
these are the cmds i typed: 
cd AA;
git clone AA -l;