# git clone+pull from a different repo on the same machine: Can i specify a filesystem path, or will it still only work with a ssh path?

Tags: git

The title pretty much covers the question. I actually had to generate an ssh key in order to get the local-checkout going. Something like this: `git clone ec2-user@localhost:/home/ec2-user/local_bare_repo.git local_normal_repo`

According to git doc,

> <repository> The "remote" repository that is the source of a fetch or
>   pull operation. This parameter can be either a URL (see the section
>   GIT URLS below) or the name of a remote (see the section REMOTES
>   below).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520121/1434136

Answer (score 1):

If you're already looking at the docs, why didn't you read the section on "Git URLs" as referred in your quote?

> For local repositories, also supported by Git natively, the following syntaxes may be used:
>      `/path/to/repo.git/`
>      `file:///path/to/repo.git/`