# Create git repo on local PC and then clone repo across local file system in linux

Tags: git, git-clone

I would like to create a git repo on my linux PC for testing so that I can then clone the repo elsewhere on my PC and do some git testing (push, pull etc...), but I don't want to use a network server - I want my local PC to also be the "repote" repo.

Part of my issue is desrcibed here for a windows box, but does not appear to work for me on my linux box: [GIT clone repo across local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system)

What I have got so far:

Make repo in /usr/local/git_root:

```
cd /usr/local/git_root
sudo mkdir testGit.git
cd testGit.git
sudo git --bare init
```

Then in my user area clone the project:

```
cd ~/sandbox
git clone file:////usr/local/git_root/gitTest.git
```

I get the error:

> fatal: '//usr/local/git_root/getTest.git' does not appear to be a git
>   repo fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're creating your repository as root. Does your user have appropriate permissions to access it?

Comment: err...no :o And then I put my repo in ~/git_root and did not use "sudo" to do anything and it all started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo, too many forward slashes:

```
git clone file:////usr/local/git_root/gitTest.git
```

should be

```
git clone file:///usr/local/git_root/gitTest.git
```

Alternatively,

```
git clone /usr/local/git_root/gitTest.git
```

---

**Edit:**

For posterity, the comment above alludes to the fact that the cloning user needs to have root access to the folder.

Comment: I tried both of these (infact I have tried all the combos in the link) and nothing is yet working :(

Comment: The "file:///usr..." version doesn't work for me, but "/usr/local..." does. You've tried that one?

Comment: I did... but then I saw the comment from hvd regarding permissions and with a combo of your answer and his comment its all working now! (both, "file:///..." and just "/...") thanks :)