# Git push error "does not appear to be a git repository" with fileshare

Tags: git, fileshare

This seems like it should be simple but I just can't get this to work and I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer using a fileshare.  I am getting an error when I push a local repository to a fileshare on a network drive.  Here is what I have done:

```
//Create The repository:
cd H:/
git init --bare --shared=group test.git
//Have also tried git init --bare test.git
```

Then I create a local repository:

```
cd MyDocuments/Test
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial Commit"
git remote add origin 'H:/test.git"
//Have also tried (among many others):
git remote add origin 'file:///fileshare/test.git'
```

I then get this error:

```
$git push origin master
fatal: '\fileshare\test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried without the quotes? `git remote add origin H:/test.git`

Comment: This worked!  But, the reason I had the quotes in the first place is my actual project has a space in the path name which, of course, doesn't add the repository as a remote and just gives me a usage error.  How can I add the repository that has a space in the path?

Comment: I propose in the answer below a few alternatives to deal with space.

Comment: Update: I have found that double quotes (") and using the backslash escape character before a space work, but a single quote does not.  Anyway, thanks a TON VonC, getting it to work in the first place got me going, I appreciate it!

Comment: Is it like the one I mention below (with a `<===`)?

Comment: Yes, except I didn't need the '\' when enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, this would work:

```
git remote add origin H:/test.git
```

For path with spaces, you can try various escape schemes:

```
git remote add origin H:/path_with\ spaces/test.git
git remote add origin "H:/path_with spaces/test.git" <===
git remote add origin H:/path_with^ spaces/test.git
```

Or use the same solution as in "[GIT clone repo across local file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2519987/6309)":

```
git remote add origin file://"H:/path_with spaces/test.git"
```