# Is it possible to get files from .git folder

Tags: git, version-control

I cloned a git repo some time ago. After cloning the repo it had source files and a `.git` folder. Now there is only the `.git` folder. Somehow the files were deleted (a long time back).

These are the contents of the `.git` folder:

```
Mic-Pro:sample.git mic$ ls
HEAD        config      config_     description hooks       info        objects     refs
```

`git status` says the directory is not a git repo. Given only that `.git` folder, is there any way to recover those files?

I can't clone the repo as its not available anymore

Comment: It sounds like the answer is pretty much as if you'd done an `rm -rf /` on your filesystem:  1) re-clone the repo (if it's still available), or 2) restore from backup (if you have one).

Comment: Can you not re-clone the repo? Also, be sure you're running `git status` in the root of the repo directory tree, not inside the `.git` folder.

Comment: @paulsm4  can't clone the repo as its not available anymore

Comment: There's also a chance that *maybe* your .,git folder is intact, and maybe you can do `git clone file:////<host>/<share>/<path>`: [Clone Git repo across local filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system-in-windows)

Comment: If the .git folder is intact you might just be able to do `git checkout HEAD` in the parent directory.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks ur trick worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
git init /tmp/recovery
cd /tmp/recovery
cp -r /path/to/broken/repo/.git/objects .git
```

More detailed: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66891/how-to-recover-broken-partially-deleted-git-repository

Comment: i tried that , it says on branch master , inital commit

Comment: Did you try to follow these steps:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66891/how-to-recover-broken-partially-deleted-git-repository

Answer (score 6):

If you have not messed the files in the '.git' folder, this command should fix your problem :

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```