# iOS Xcode 8 cannot change git origin

Tags: ios, git, github

I'm working with an old Xcode project. I want to change its `git origin` to mine. But some how cannot change. And all the source control is greyed out. How can I recreate git and push to remote (I already has a remote git at GitHub setup)?

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to clone the repo?

Comment: Hi the repo is from my project mate from external hdd. the remote repo is not up to date. I need to start with this local repo then upload to server

Comment: Try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system-in-windows

Comment: the problem is that my local git is unknown which mean this project does not have local git to clone

Comment: If you have all the source code delete the .git folder and init a new repo.

Comment: Thanks, I manage to manually create .git and then make initial commit from terminal then push to remote