# Cannot push using ip address after update git for windows to version 2.11

Tags: windows, git

I just upgraded git for windows to version 2.11 and now I can't push if my repo address starts with ip e.g. //192.168.1.1

Is it because of the double forward slash?

below is the error message:

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master

Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 669 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: object directory /192.168.2.68/git/videoHandler.git/objects does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: fatal: unresolved deltas left after unpacking
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To //192.168.2.68/git/videoHandler.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '//192.168.2.68/git/videoHandler.git'


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (1859 ms @ 09-Dec-16 4:07:23 PM)
```

`git remote show origin` :

```
remote origin
  Fetch URL: //192.168.2.68/git/videoHandler.git
  Push  URL: //192.168.2.68/git/videoHandler.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branch:
    master tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system-in-windows

Comment: thanks but i tried the suggestion "file://\\\\ip" and "file:////ip" and both do not work

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` says?

Comment: @Christoph please refers to my edit above

Comment: Your remote seems to be ok, upstream is set for push and pull. Is [that](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/object-directory-does-not-exist-git-operations-fail-after-upgrade-or-stash_home-update-650413082.html) what happend?

Comment: I think it looks similar. Can this be fixed? I'm temporary switching back to version 2.9 and push is working fine.