# Can you clone a repo that is a clone of a git repo using LFS?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Say there is a repo, A, which uses git LFS. And you have a clone of that, repo B. Can you create another clone, repo C, from repo B or do you have to go directly to repo A?

I ask because the network configuration makes it difficult to go directly from C to A, plus there is some stuff in B that I want that should not really be pushed to A.

When I tried, it looked like it cloned the repo okay but failed during the checkout with this error:

> Error downloading object: <filepath> (<sha>): Smudge error: Error downloading <filepath> (<fullsha>): EOF

When I tried specifying the remote path as `//SERVERNAME/path/repo` instead of `file://SERVERNAME/path/repo`, it failed around the same point in the checkout with an "unknown protocol" error.

Note that none of the repos are on servers, but instead are on local or network drives.

Comment: Try adding 2 slashes: `file:////SERVERNAME/path/repo`. See these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59153626/152016 (for local cloning) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520121/152016 (for LAN cloning)